# Calculating probability using normal tables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've had a crack at this question however I don't seem to be getting the correct answer and I can't figure out why. I've been given a table of the 'Normal Distribution Function' where the left tail is tabulated for $0\leq x\leq 4$.

> Given that $Z\sim N(0,1)$, what is the value of $P(-1.1 < Z < 0.35)$
>   to 4 decimal places?

My working is as follows:
Rearranging the equation first then looking up the values in the given tables.
$$P(Z < 0.35) - P(X > -1.1)$$
$$P(Z < 0.35) - P(X < 1.1)$$
$$0.6368 - 0.8643 = -0.2275$$

The given answer for this question is $0.5011$.

Could someone please explain where I'm falling short and how to correctly solve this question?

Comment: You want $\Pr(X\lt 0.35)-\Pr(X\le -1.1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you please explain why I need $\Pr(X\le -1.1)$ instead of  the way I had it in my working?

Comment: Draw a normal curve. You want the area under the normal curve, from $-1.1$ to $0.35$. That area is the area to the left of $z=0.35$ minus the area to the left of $-1.1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\Pr(Z\lt 0.35)-\Pr(Z\le -1.1)$.

The table does not have direct information about $\Pr(Z\le a)$ for negative $a$.

But by symmetry we have $\Pr(Z\le -1.1)=\Pr(Z\ge 1.1)$.

Note that $\Pr(Z\ge 1.1)=1-\Pr(Z\lt 1.1)$.

Now you have all the needed components.